# How to use ffpyplayer in Python/Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Project is made with `python 3.9.6` and `kivy 2.0.0`. In my project I have button that plays audio with `kivy`'s `soundloadre`. `Kivy`'s `sdl2_audio` is kind of buggy and because of that I want to use `ffpyplayer`. So basically I want to play audio with **only** `ffpyplayer`. Here's my `python` code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

class MainWidget(MDFloatLayout):

    def play_on(self):
        self.ids.my_image.source = 'icons/play_pressed.png'
        click = SoundLoader.load('sounds/click_effect.wav')
        if click:
            click.play()

    def play_off(self):
        self.ids.my_image.source = 'icons/play.png'
        myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left', duration=.25)
        myapp.screen_manager.current = 'Second'
```

And here's my `kivy` code:

```
<MainWidget>:

    Button:
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        pos_hint: {'x': .39, 'y': .1}
        size_hint: .28, .15
        on_press: root.play_on()
        on_release: root.play_off()

        Image:
            id: my_image
            source: "icons/play.png"
            size: 350, 350
            allow_stretch: True
            allow_ratio: True
            keep_ratio: True
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very top of the file set:

```py
import os
os.environ["KIVY_AUDIO"] = "ffpyplayer"
# other imports
```

You can read about controlling the environment [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/environment.html)

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. But it's delaying and do you know how to fix this delay?

Comment: Do you mean the import itself? If yes, then this is normal)

Comment: Audio is delaying. It was playing as soon as I clicked the button, but now it's playing after i click the button. And delay is pretty noticeable. Or will it fix it's self when i convert it to apk with buildozer?

Comment: Can you add a small working example in your question (with widgets)? I will check

Comment: I will update the question for you to make it more comfortable.

Comment: You can throw a link to the file, this will also work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235417/discussion-between-neizvestnyj-and-gurami-supatashvili).